# SetListAdapter method call doesnt work from service?

Tags: android

Here I have a strange problem, there is a method which refreshes my listview :

```
 setListAdaptor();
```

Whenever I call this method from my service ( in proper way ) whenever a presence changed to update the list:

```
  @Override
public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {

       BusProvider.getInstance().post(new Reload());
     //  Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ",presence.getFrom() + "presenceChanged    
 "+presence.getStatus());
   }
```

It doesnt work, but when i bind the method to onitemclick , on the listview, it does the job perfectly, does any one know why is that?  i have tried the runOnUiThread too!

Comment: used Handler and worked, how ever its still really strange

Answer (score 2):

Used a Handler and worked , how ever its really strange

well i had the SetAdapterList method in a fragment and because fragments dont run on main thread - because the activity which has the tab pager is actually the main thread and thats why we call getactivity() in fragments instead (this) - i could not call it from a non UI or non main (main thread is the UI thread) thread, so for doing so i needed to create a method (Handler mHandler = new Handler(); ) and use it to post what i needed to do in that - with a static method or in my case eventBus Otto <3 - thats all.. aaand the so the reason it was working from OnListItemClick method was because it was obviously called from UI Thread..

Comment: you should provide a more detailled answer to what you did and how it worked.